# How does Google's APK Expansion Zip Library read zipped files without unzipping them?

Tags: android

Google provides [APK Expansion Zip Library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files#ZipLib) as a way to read file in zipped format. It creates a virtual file system for the zipped file. However, how could this possible?

Does it mean we can read file without unzipping it firstly? Or it just unzip the file when it's needed? I can't find any documentation on how it works

Answer (score 0):

> Does it mean we can read file without unzipping it firstly?

It depends what you mean by unzipping. Is there a process where the entire contents is decompressed with each individual uncompressed file stored on the device? No. It doesn't do that.

What happens is that when you read a bit of a file, then it'll inflate (unzip) a chunk that's big enough to satisfy your request.

Such an approach is OK for when you're just reading sequentially, but it's not going to be great at seeking. When you seek forwards, you're effectively going to be unzipping and discarding data, and seeking backwards looks like it isn't supported.

The other thing to bear in mind is that some file types are stored in the expansion apk without compression. This is useful for when you do need random access, or for filetypes that are already compressed (e.g. .mp3 files).